# PHP: Find and replace with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable which contains email addresses.

Examples:

```
    $email[1]="email(at)test.com";
    $email[2]="email[at]test.com";
    $email[3]="email(a)test.com";
    $email[4]="email(alfa)test.com";
    $email[5]="email[a]test.com";
```

How can I to perform in PHP a regex find all between () and [] and replace with "@". so in the end it will be like this:

```
    $email[1]="email@test.com";
    $email[2]="email@test.com";
    $email[3]="email@test.com";
    $email[4]="email@test.com";
    $email[5]="email@test.com";
```

All i have at the moment is this ((([a-zA-Z]+))|([[a-zA-Z]+]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
[(\[][a-z]+[)\]]
```

Replacement string:

```
@
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qQ1uQ3/4)

**Example:**

```
<?php
$string = 'email(alfa)test.com';
$pattern = '~[(\[][a-z]+[)\]]~';
$replacement = '@';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> email@test.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~[([][^])]+[\])]~', '@', $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

- `~[([]` matches an opening bracket or brace
- `[^])]+` matches any chars that are not a closing bracket or brace
- `[\])]` matches a closing bracket or brace
- We replace with `@`

Comment: FYI, this simple solution will work regardless of what we have inside the braces: for instance, `(a.t.)` and `[a-t]` will also work.